# SQL group data by 2 column

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I having issue in grouping 2 columns,keep getting error :

> Column '#TEM1.STATUS' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

below are my stored procedure code :

```
SELECT COUNT(Employee_ID),Roster_Code,STATUS
FROM #TEM1 GROUP BY Roster_Code,Department
```

TEM1 table actually is a temporary table.i want to group them by department and roster code.
below is my TEM1 data:
[image]

my expected output :

[image]

Comment: You should use PIVOT I guess.

Comment: The error is exactly what is in the error message. Stop selecting `STATUS`.

Comment: but status is important,for counting absent or present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying "GROUP BY Roster_Code,Department" basically means that you expect to see one row in the output for each different combination of Roster_Code and Department which exists in the table.

For example, the output would contain one row for Roster_Code=A, Department=HRS. But there are some rows in this group with STATUS=IN, and other with STATUS=ABSENT. So it is not clear what you expect to be displayed in the output in this situation, and so you see an error message.

This is why you cannot simply select 'STATUS' - you either need to include it in the GROUP BY clause (so you would have different rows in the output for each STATUS) or to use some aggregate function which tells SQL Server how to combine the multiple values into a single value which it can output.

It looks like what you are actually trying to do is to *count* the number of employees with 'IN' statuses, and the total number of employees. This probably means that you will want to use the COUNT() aggregate function.

Here is a step towards the output you want:

```
SELECT Department,
       Roster_Code,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS='IN' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) IN_STATUSES,
       COUNT(*) TOTAL_STATUSES
FROM #TEM1 GROUP BY Department, Roster_Code
```

It looks like you also want to classify any roster code other than A/B/D/E as 'Other', so we can add another step to do that:

```
SELECT Department, 
       Roster_Code, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS='IN' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) IN_STATUSES,
       COUNT(*) TOTAL_STATUSES
FROM
(
    SELECT Department,
           CASE WHEN Roster_Code IN ('A','B','D','E') THEN Roster_Code ELSE 'Other' END Roster_Code,
           STATUS
    FROM #TEM1
) x
GROUP BY Department, Roster_Code
```

It looks like you also want to perform a "pivot" operation, which will take the separate rows we currently have for A/B/D/E/Other and convert these into their own columns in a single row. Then, you will want to combine the status counts we currently have into strings of the form "3/4" - this is just a case of concatenating them (e.g. IN_STATUSES + '/' + TOTAL_STATUSES).